# Scale and translate path from one coordinate system to another

Tags: geometry, linear-algebra, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I have a path output as shown in the image below, in a coordinate system 1 wherein the start point and the end point are (40,40) and (10,20) respectively.

I want to scale this path to a new coordinate system (coordinate system 2) with a known start and end point, the path has to scale and adjust between the new points.

I believe Affine transforms might help / linear algebra.
How do I achieve this ? and will this be accurate or will it distort ?

[image: image showing two cordinate systems]

Answer (score 0):

To find appropriate affine tranformation (there are many ways to transform two points into two another ones, but we choose the simplest way), you can apply these elementary steps:

```
Shift coordinates by (-startx, -starty) 
Scale along X-axis with coefficient (newendx-newstartx)/(endx-startx)  (here -80/3)
Scale along Y-axis with coefficient (newendy-newstarty)/(endy-starty)   (here -35)
Shift coordinates by (newstartx, newstarty)
```

Resulting affine tranformation is product of these four matrices

[Using Wolfram alpha to get matrix](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=M%3D%5B%5B1%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%2C0%5D%2C%5Ba%2C%20b%2C%201%5D%5D*%5B%5Bc%2C%200%2C%200%5D%2C%5B0%2C%20d%2C%200%5D%2C%5B0%2C%200%20%2C1%5D%5D*%5B%5B1%2C%200%2C%200%5D%2C%5B0%2C%201%2C%200%5D%2C%5Be%2C%20f%20%2C1%5D%5D)

```
M == {{c,       0,       0},
      {0,       d,       0}, 
      {a*c + e, b*d + f, 1}}
```

where `a,b,c,d,e,f` are values from decription above (`a = -startx` and so on)

Now transform coordinates with multiplication of point coordinates and matrix M

```
 (x, y, 1) * M =  (newx, newy, 1)
```

Comment: could you please elaborate on how to use the matrices ?